# gmap4rails box showing up under map won't go away

Tags: maps

There's this box that I can get to go away under my maps. I have a main map for my index and another map for show. I have the map options different for both of them. When I look at my page source I see my scripts for both maps. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"description":"test, 217 cleveland ave , liverpool, This is some additional information.","lat":43.1155,"lng":-76.2292},{"description":"bah, 215 university place, syracuse, ","lat":43.0396,"lng":-76.1355}];
Gmaps.map.markers_conf.do_clustering = true;
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script>


`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = false;
Gmaps.map.map_options.zoom = 10;
Gmaps.map.map_options.detect_location = true;
Gmaps.map.map_options.center_on_user = false;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"description":"test, 217 cleveland ave , liverpool, This is some additional information.","lat":43.1155,"lng":-76.2292},{"description":"bah, 215 university place, syracuse, ","lat":43.0396,"lng":-76.1355}];
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making .map_container twice as small as the map height. My map height is 400px and my map container height is 200px. I still don't know why that would happen.

Comment: I correctly fixed my problem this time by assigning different CSS classes to each map in map options. example- :container_class => 'map1'